# Удалить Fixture коллизию объекта

Tags: android-studio, разработка-игр, libgdx

У меня есть объекты (пули) с текстурой и коллизией в виде Fixture и когда мне нужно удалить эти объекты, я их удаляю из массива обработки, но при этом коллизия остается и продолжает двигаться,создавая помехи в игре. Как можно удалить/отключить эту коллизию? Я пробовал через `setActiv`... и через `destroyFixture` и через `removeBody`, но у меня появлялась ошибка:

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>   Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам спросил - сам нашел ответ:

```
 world.destroyBody(body.getBody());
 body = null;
```

В моем случае body = Fixture, a не Body, у вас же может быть:

```
 world.destroyBody(body);
 body = null;
```